# Silverlight combobox dropdown text/value

Tags: silverlight

Is there anyway in Silverlight combobox to specify a value and a text like an html dropdownlist?  I only see a content property.  I read that I could use the tag property but I am not able to retrieve the value from the code behind when doing...

```
mycombobox.Tag.toString();
```

Anyone know of the best way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you talking about `SelectedItem` / `SelectedValue`?

Comment: You can fill it with strings but it\`s basically not SL way, so I suggest to use proper binding capabilities. There are many examples out there, like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157282/Binding-to-a-ComboBox-in-Silverlight-A-Gotcha).

Comment: The best way is to use Binding.

Answer (score 0):

Have a custom class that can hold 2 properties to represent the value and text fields of a drop down item. And bind the list of that class as the ItemsSource of the combobox.

you could try

```
public class CustomComboBoxItem
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myComboboxSource = new List<CustomComboBoxItem>();
        myComboboxSource.Add(new CustomComboBoxItem { Key = 1, DisplayText = "First Text" });
        myComboboxSource.Add(new CustomComboBoxItem { Key = 2, DisplayText = "Second Text" });
    }

    public List<CustomComboBoxItem> myComboboxSource { get; set; }
```

In Xaml,

```
<ComboBox Name="myCombobox" Height="25" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding myComboboxSource, ElementName= mainPage}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText"/>        


<Button Click="Button_Click" Height="25" Width="100" Content="Get Selected Value"/>
```

You can test the selected value by using

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(myCombobox.SelectedValue));
    }
```